'IValidationContext' does not contain a definition for 'CloneForChildValidator'
Im getting this error after i upgrade my fluent Validation package from 8.6.3 to 9.2.2
Could someone please help ?
public class PolymorphicValidator<TBaseClass> : NoopPropertyValidator
        where TBaseClass : class
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, IValidator> _derivedValidators = new Dictionary<Type, IValidator>();

    public PolymorphicValidator<TBaseClass> Add<TDerived>(IValidator<TDerived> derivedValidator) where TDerived : TBaseClass
    {
        _derivedValidators[typeof(TDerived)] = derivedValidator;
        return this;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<ValidationFailure> Validate(PropertyValidatorContext context)
    {
              }

    private IEnumerable<ValidationFailure> ValidateType(TBaseClass item, PropertyValidatorContext context, int index)
    {
        var actualType = item.GetType();
        if (_derivedValidators.TryGetValue(actualType, out var derivedValidator))
        {
            var newContext = context.ParentContext.CloneForChildValidator(item);
            newContext.PropertyChain.Add(context.Rule.PropertyName);
            newContext.PropertyChain.AddIndexer(index);
            return derivedValidator.Validate(newContext).Errors;
        }
        return Enumerable.Empty<ValidationFailure>();
    }
}



As stated in 9.0 Upgrade Guide, the non-generic ValidationContext had been migrated to the generic class ValidationContext<T> or non-generic IValidationContext.
Reference from the PolymorphicValidator, you can access the CloneForChildValidator method from the context.ParentContext via ValidationContext<T>.GetFromNonGenericContext(IValidationContext context) method.
var parentContext = ValidationContext<TBaseClass>.GetFromNonGenericContext(context.ParentContext);
var newContext = parentContext.CloneForChildValidator(item);

